# Adding text beneath a row of images using CSS

Tags: html, css, web

[image]I've been stuck on this for hours and for some reason I can't figure out why I can't add text below images with links. I have no problem adding text below images with no links, but when I add the extra line for a url, it doesn't format properly.

```
<div class = "wrapper">
<a href = "">
     <img src = ""/>
     <span class="text">something</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class = "wrapper">
<a href = "">
    <img src = ""/>
    <span class="text">something</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class = "wrapper">
<a href = "">
    <img src = ""/>
    <span class="text">something</span>
</a>
</div>
```

My css is as follows:

```
.wrapper
{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width:220px;
}

img
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 160px;
    float:left;*/
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

.text
{   
    display:block;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `"doesn't format properly"`... try `format: proper`. Or at least tell/show us what it looks like now and how it should be.

Comment: uploaded pic of output

Comment: And how would you like it, 3 images in a row and a span below each?

Comment: yes, thats why ive been trying to get

Comment: I wrote you an answer - the problem was that you were putting a margin on the images only, not the text. Either put it on both, or their container elements (suggested).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 3 images in a row and a text below each, you should modify the wrapper element a bit because you're only giving the left margin to the image, and not to the text. You can either add it to the text as well, or put it on the wrapper:

160px between each image:

```css
.wrapper {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
}

body {width: 1400px}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

No offset, looks better as a snippet here:

```css
.wrapper {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 170px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
}

body {width: 520px}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <span class="text">something</span>
  </a>
</div>
```